# How can i simplify a oneliner javascript code like this

Tags: javascript

I was recently converting an obfuscated js code to python I'm not good at js when I saw this I had no clue what to do is there anyway to convert this to simple js code

`return 12 === selector ? (data = data >> 4, outstring = outstring + String.fromCharCode(data)) : 18 === selector && (data = data >> 2, outstring = outstring + String.fromCharCode((65280 & data) >> 8), outstring = outstring + String.fromCharCode(255 & data)), outstring;`

Comment: @Selvin is there anything to make it simplified ?

Comment: What do you expect from a simplified output? What do you think simplified means?

Comment: i meant it as a line by line with return outstring; in a single line rather everything in a single line

Comment: You can put it on multiple lines by adding them yourself. Why do you need our help? What do you actually want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i just wanted it to be in multiple lines than one single i already got the answer to it anyway @Community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is somewhat simplified version of your code:

```
if (selector === 12) {
  data = data >> 4; // or data = Math.floor(data / 16), which is do right shift operation with data by 4 bits; 16 means 2 to the power of 4
  outstring += String.fromCharCode(data); // append char value of data
  return outstring;
} else if (selector === 18) {
  data = data >> 2;
  outstring = outstring + String.fromCharCode((65280 & data) >> 8); // turn higher 8 of 16 bits to a character and append
  outstring = outstring + String.fromCharCode(255 & data); // turn lower 8 of 16 bits to a character and append
}
return outstring;
```

If you are completely new to JS, you will probably find links
[String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) and [Right shift (>>)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Right_shift) helpful